# Push dictionary? How to achieve this in Lua?

Tags: dictionary, lua, lua-table

Say I have this dictionary in Lua

```
places = {dest1 = 10, dest2 = 20, dest3 = 30}
```

In my program I check if the dictionary has met my size limit in this case 3, how do I push the oldest key/value pair out of the dictionary and add a new one?

```
places["newdest"] = 50

--places should now look like this, dest3 pushed off and newdest added and dictionary has kept its size

places = {newdest = 50, dest1 = 10, dest2 = 20}
```

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Dictionary keys don't save them in the order you input them, not like indices, so I don't know that you'll be able to push it to the front. You /can/ do it with an index table (which I wrote a function for before realizing you wanted dictionary).

Comment: @lhf just for scripting a game, I needed a dictionary that has a fixed size and pushes out the oldest key/value pair when a new pair is added(once the fixed size has been reached).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too difficult to do this, if you *really* needed it, and it's easily reusable as well.

```
local function ld_next(t, i) -- This is an ordered iterator, oldest first.
  if i <= #t then
    return i + 1, t[i], t[t[i]]
  end
end

local limited_dict = {__newindex = function(t,k,v)
  if #t == t[0] then -- Pop the last entry.
    t[table.remove(t, 1)] = nil
  end
  table.insert(t, k)
  rawset(t, k, v)
end, __pairs = function(t)
  return ld_next, t, 1
end}

local t = setmetatable({[0] = 3}, limited_dict)

t['dest1'] = 10
t['dest2'] = 20
t['dest3'] = 30
t['dest4'] = 50

for i, k, v in pairs(t) do print(k, v) end
```

```
dest2   20
dest3   30
dest4   50
```

The order is stored in the numeric indices, with the `0`th index indicating the limit of unique keys that the table can have.

Comment: Thanks, this worked the simplest for me.
Although some of its a little over my head so I'm kind of using it blindly, heh.

Answer (score 0):

Given that dictionary keys do not save their entered position, I wrote something that should be able to help you accomplish what you want, regardless.

```
function push_old(t, k, v)
  local z = fifo[1]
  t[z] = nil
  t[k] = v
  table.insert(fifo, k)
  table.remove(fifo, 1)
end
```

You would need to create the fifo table first, based on the order you entered the keys (for instance, fifo = {"dest3", "dest2", "dest1"}, based on your post, from first entered to last entered), then use:

```
push_old(places, "newdest", 50)
```

and the function will do the work. Happy holidays!

Comment: Why create a new table in `fifo_push`?

Comment: Since fifo is an index table of values entered, I guess I figured the way I rebuilt it would be the most advantageous way for a "First in, First Out" model. Editing it now for a cleaner function. Thanks!